# Inclusion-exclusion in a set of multivariables

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, st.statistics, geometric-probability

I want to determine the risk of a multi-asset portfolio, in a way different from previous attempts. It is because current methods focus on just the correlation coefficient of two variables, while in a portfolio a group of stocks may have correlated meaningfully. After a while of deliberation, I noticed that an extended version of $\textbf{inclusion-exclusion principle}$ in simple probability for joint distributions lives up to my expectations. I'm clueless can I generalize this notion to joint probability distributions like in the following?

$ \int\int\dots\int f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})\,dx_{1}dx_{2}...dx_{n} = \sum \int f(x_{i})\,dx_{i}-\sum \int\int f(x_{i},x_{j})\,dx_{i}dx_{j} + \sum \int\int\int f(x_{i},x_{j},x_{t})\,dx_{i}dx_{j}dx_{t} - ... $

Comment: It appears that you are using the symbol $f$ to stand for a function of a single variable, and also a function of two variables, and a function of three variables, ..., and a function of $n$ variables. This is problematic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In fact, I wanted to show joint distribution of variables, and this distribution function differs for x1,...x2, and combination of them.